# What may be causing conflicts in Whirlpool implementation versions?

Tags: hash, implementation, openssl

I see by layman articles (e.g. at Wikipedia) that [the Whirlpool hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whirlpool_%28cryptography%29) has seemingly three current versions. That is to say, they are referenced as `Whirlpool-0` (original reference code), `Whirlpool-T`, an optimised for hardware version which was changed to whirlpool (let’s call it *“current”*) due to a somewhat weakening in a diffusion matrix (according to article).

Now, I see some python implementations do indeed use that *“current”* version. However, I have been using `librhash` on Linux (i.e. `rhash -W \$file`) and I’m verifying things with OpenSSL (`openssl dgst -whirlpool \$file`).

OpenSSL and rHash are consistent with each other, but different from the current version. I also noticed that OpenSSL and rHash do ***not*** seem to correlate to either of the previous versions.

Why is this so? Has there been some undocumented update to the default Whirlpool s-boxes or something? Is there a version conflict, or has there been a Whirlpool update I may have missed?

Comment: Great, what I would think would be a fairly important hashing function seems to have a 'version 4' shared among openssl, rhash and perl , yet no one seems to have anything to add about this. This must obviously be entirely uninteresting to people in cryptography and my first ever question on here must have been an utter joke.

Comment: @Mal Not at all! Knowledge of crypto in general is relatively scarce compared to some other subjects, especially as the subjects get more specific. I doubt it's even been seen by enough people yet. I'll tell you what, if you don't get an answer, I'll put a bounty on your question to encourage someone to answer it. [A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Dear Mal, first of all: Welcome to Crypto.SE! Now, as you might have noticed, I have converted your "answer" into a comment (as it does not answer your question). Don’t get me wrong, but there is a difference between answers and comments – [our help-center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help) is pretty good at explaining how things work around here. You might want to check it out. If you have any questions related to the help center or this site, please feel invited to ask me or one of the other moderators via [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). We’ll gladly help wherever we can.

Comment: As for your comment saying no one seems to care – please note your Q is merely a day old and only had 36 views while I am writing this. So, not many people have seen your Q yet, which already explains the lack of answers. One of the reasons for this is simple: **timezones**! Half the planet (USA, Asia, etc.) was sleeping while you posted your question and chances are, they’ll see (and probably answer your Q) as soon as they wake up, login at Crypto.SE and check for new Qs – which includes yours. I’m afraid you’ll have to be a bit more patient. I hope that helps and explains some things to you…

Comment: Thank you to both Rose and you e-sushi. I realise I must have sounded a bit snappy but I just found it so basic a question I thought it would be pointed out quickly. Also, I cannot comment because not enough reputation. (I am doing a double folly here, I know but I understand I shouldn't and will refrain from doing so in the future). I think one should be able to comment on one's one questions without 50 rep points (because how will one get them in the first place?). Sorry, despite reading often on the *.stack exchange, I have never really quite known how it works.
-Mali-.

Comment: Are you sure there is no gremlin (like a rogue terminating byte) in the input you feed to OpenSSL and rHash? At least, check if the file size is what it should be. You would not be the first one to be caught by that.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference.

The wiki page you referred to contains examples of hashes for all three versions of Whirlpool. For string "***The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog***", the *current* version should produce the following hash:

```
    B97DE512E91E3828B40D2B0FDCE9CEB3C4A71F9BEA8D88E75C4FA854DF36725F
    D2B52EB6544EDCACD6F8BEDDFEA403CB55AE31F03AD62A5EF54E42EE82C3FB35
```

Let's create a file containing this string and test different implementations.

```
    $ openssl dgst -whirlpool quick.txt
    whirlpool(quick.txt)= b97de512e91e3828b40d2b0fdce9ceb3c4a71f9bea8d88e75c4fa854df36725fd2b52eb6544edcacd6f8beddfea403cb55ae31f03ad62a5ef54e42ee82c3fb35

    $ rhash -W quick.txt
    b97de512e91e3828b40d2b0fdce9ceb3c4a71f9bea8d88e75c4fa854df36725fd2b52eb6544edcacd6f8beddfea403cb55ae31f03ad62a5ef54e42ee82c3fb35  quick.txt
```

Both match the hash from the wiki.
Let's test the python implementation using this script:

```
    import whirlpool

    wp = whirlpool.new("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
    hashed_string = wp.hexdigest()

    print(hashed_string)
```

The output is:

```
    b97de512e91e3828b40d2b0fdce9ceb3c4a71f9bea8d88e75c4fa854df36725fd2b52eb6544edcacd6f8beddfea403cb55ae31f03ad62a5ef54e42ee82c3fb35
```

Let's test the reference code from the Whirlpool home page by inserting the following lines at the end of `makeISOTestVectors()` function:

```
    const char* quick = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    NESSIEinit(&w);
    NESSIEadd(quick, 8*strlen(quick), &w);
    NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);
    printf("The hash-code is the following 512-bit string.\n\n");
    display(digest, DIGESTBYTES); printf("\n\n");
    fflush(stdout);
```

The output is:

```
    B97DE512E91E3828 B40D2B0FDCE9CEB3 C4A71F9BEA8D88E7 5C4FA854DF36725F
    D2B52EB6544EDCAC D6F8BEDDFEA403CB 55AE31F03AD62A5E F54E42EE82C3FB35
```

All implementations produce the same hash. Where did you found a mismatching version?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance.. Are these your sources: [cppcrypto on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcrypto/). If so, would you email me at *noloader, gmail account*. I based an implementation of Kalyna on your gear. I want to get some information from you so I can cite your work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I will attempt answering this myself. Given that (at least on linux), perl, openssl have gone down the same path as the rhash author (I am not sure who in fact, implemented this first), the reason for a different digest, is that, due to restricting the input message from $2^{512}$ bits to $2^{64}$ bits max, the first $512$ rows of $4 \times 32$-bit hex words of the S-boxes have been kept, and the last $512$ rows of the tables have been truncated.

I am not in the position of evaluating the security implications of this, and thus do not wish to accept this answer by myself yet (hoping for more professional input).

If however, solid user bases such as perl and openssl use it, I am inclined to suppose this is a viable implementation.

As a sub-question then, I still wonder why this has not been 'updated' as a 'version 4' or a $64$-bit input version more clearly?

EDIT: The "latter half" of S-boxes I thought were truncated are in fact, obsoleted ones from the reference code. This leads to my assumption being wrong and now for sure, it seems there is this version 4 out in the wild.

Surely, with an important hash as whirlpool, someone would have some insight into this. reference code asserts python code != {perl,openssl,rhash}!

To add to answer above, as I can't comment on it?

EDIT to Kerukuro: I can't comment?

on arch linux, (I also asked someone on another distro), I get :

```
cat quick.txt
```

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    cat quick.txt | wc 
1 9 44

openssl dgst -whirlpool quick.txt

whirlpool(quick.txt)= 72687676756b91ad986f2e56df761b354b748bc20098354b017b924e82cc67ae059da85f009d1a17c0f12ec0e644c0c3a193f3fc0fee22f053edbfcd95cbf873

same intel sandy bridge (arch 64 bit distro):
rhash -W quick.txt

72687676756b91ad986f2e56df761b354b748bc20098354b017b924e82cc67ae059da85f009d1a17c0f12ec0e644c0c3a193f3fc0fee22f053edbfcd95cbf873  quick.txt

perl: whirlpoolsum quick.txt 
Possible precedence issue with control flow operator at /usr/bin/vendor_perl/whirlpoolsum line 227.
72687676756b91ad986f2e56df761b354b748bc20098354b017b924e82cc67ae059da85f009d1a17c0f12ec0e644c0c3a193f3fc0fee22f053edbfcd95cbf873  quick.txt

The other examples you mention produce the expected result (python, reference nessie source).

So, just to summarise: python does catch the newlines, and for rhash, openssl and echoing, one should do for correct hashing:

echo "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" | tr -d '\n' | openssl dgst -whirlpool

Comment: "To add to answer above, as I can't comment on it?" - you could comment on it if you were logged in as the account which asked the question. You seem to have ended up with separate registered and unregistered accounts: a mod might be able to merge them for you.

Comment: As for the discrepancy, try stripping the line break then hashing it, i.e. `echo -n "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" > quick.txt`. That'll give you `wc` = `0 9 43` and will match the reference hash.

Comment: Yes, rup.. I thought I HAD.. and I have't , coupled with the fact I don't know python and python on the same files produced different hashes has led me on a wild goosechas. I am very sorry for that. Accidents almost never occcur due to a single point of failure!! :) I wuld just accept the answer of Keruko or so but I can't as I don't think the question realises I am the OP. PS> Sorry about the noise e-rose! :)

Comment: @Mali Do we agree that Keruko should be given the bounty?

Comment: Sure. If you are fine with it. :) [About the accounts. Well, no, it seemed to link my 'mal' with some (guest) mal who posted eons ago. So when I registered, whilst asking this, it thinks I am not OP :) ]. The answer was a mix of openssl channel, keruko and rup. I thought I had removed the trailing \n, but I had been removing \0 and it didn't add up. So sorry for any inconvenience!